# wiring multiple sensors with one PLC

Tags: sensors, modbus, plc

Is it possible to wire multiple sensors with one PLC (let's say S7 CPU 1511C-1 PN) over Modbus or Profinet without additional modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. There should be a module at the other end of Modbus or Profibus cable. You have to convert sensor signal to digital values inside PLC, that is why.

If you have a sensor that can be connected to Modbus or Profibus directly, the answer to your question is still "No it is not possible" because technically this is sensor with built-in module, and it means that although you connect sensor, you in reality you connect I\O module built on top of sensor.

I think this is important to understand, that you cannot connect sensors directly to any field bus without field bus coupler.

Comment: I'm aware that pure sensors or transducers can only be connected to PLCs via analog inputs. What I'm talking about are sensors with integrated RS485 output port like this one http://automation-x.com/Tektrol_Coriolis-Flow-Meter-1100A-2-1-050A-2-S-600-1-G.html?sc=27&category=16840596

Comment: which you never stated in your question. Anyway note that RS485 does not tell you, that you can connect, it is interface only. Sensor have to support modbus or profinet, with is very rare case. Usually sensors have RS485 with simple protocols like M-Bus or even custom protocols with you will have to read in PLC manually.

Comment: as mentioned in a comment above, they are industrial sensors with transmitters that support a combination of Profibus DP, HART, frequency and 20mA outputs. look here http://automation-x.com/Tektrol_Coriolis-Flow-Meter-1100A-2-1-050A-2-S-600-1-G.html?sc=27&category=16840596

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Profinet, Profibus DP or Profibus PA, and Modbus, you can connect several sensors to that bus systems. The count and the distance are limited. What you need is a good bus cable, with Profinet you need an additional Profinet switch and the right terminals, possibly also bus termination which are e.g. integrated in the Profibus DP connectors. Be aware to terminate the bus, especially with Modbus, and also spend you money to not make to much stubs in the bus line and use the right impedance for your bus cable.

Comment: If I understood, no additional communication modules are needed. CPU with one Profibus/modbus port could be connected to many sensors if the we respect the distance limit. If possible, do you have an example of such scenario.

Comment: I developed Profibus slaves 15 years ago, several devices namely density meters "Anton Paar" (process devices) where connected on one Profibus DP. Which sensors do you want to connect to your PLC? I used an S7-400 with a Profibus DP module for testing integration.

Comment: With Profinet, this is over like Ethernet, I think you will need an additional switch.

Comment: like Ethernet switch? The Profibus connector on the PLC is a DB9 not RJ45!! Maybe I'm getting it wrong

Comment: Which kind of sensors do you want to connect to the PLC, you're absolutely right, the Profibus-Connector is a DB9 Profibus-Connector. Do not confuse Profinet with Profibus. Profinet is RJ45 and close to Ethernet standard, Profibus is a  RS-485 Bus-System, but has a little difference electronic vaules (impedance, terminations) as the RS-485 standard.

Comment: I get it now. I examined the datasheet of the sensors and I found that they provide RS485, Profibus, Profinet and Modbus. I also want connect a motor drive.

Comment: That might be expensive sensors delivering all these bus systems at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - **YES**. If you're using S7 CPU 1511C-1 PN, then you can wire multiple sensors using ModbusTCP or ProfiNet.

To clarify a bit about Modbus - it is a communication protocol, which only defines how to interpret received data/form requests (how to arrange 1s and 0s). It was developed for single master - multiple slave communication.

However, a number of different physical interfaces are used to send the raw Modbus data (1s and 0s as electrical signals), and they have their own limitations. For example:

- RS232 + Modbus - usually 1-to-1 communications, because that's a limitation of RS232 standard (some workarounds are sometimes used).
- RS485 + Modbus - single master, multiple slave communication - you could connect multiple sensors. I'm assuming sensors behave as slaves.
- TCP/IP + Modbus (ModbusTCP) - single master, multiple slave communication - you could connect multiple sensors. Furthermore, it is possible to do multi-master multi-slave communications, if you know what you're doing and can compromise on some things.

The PLC you mentioned will probably do ModbusTCP, as it only has Ethernet port.

Regarding ProfiNet - it is a standard which defines physical interface and communication protocol. You can use it to connect to multiple devices as it's Ethernet based.